# Print line numbers for lines containing a specific integer

Tags: python, regex

I have tried this

```
import itertools
import numpy as np

with open('base.txt','r') as f:
    lst = map(int, itertools.imap(float, f))

num=1200

for line in lst:
    if num == line:
        print (line)
```

Just prints 1200...

I thought of re than

```
import re
import itertools

with open('base.txt','r') as f:
    lst = map(int, itertools.imap(float, f))

p = re.compile(r'(\d+)')

num=1200

for line in lst:
    if num in p.findall(line):
        print line
```

But I got

```
  File "a7.py", line 12, in <module>
    if num in p.findall(line) :
TypeError: expected string or buffer
```

What I want is the all line numbers that contain 1200.File has numerical inputs one by line,I have checked this.

Comment: I'm confused why you map float, then map int back over the float values...

Comment: Does the file contain numerical inputs as floats, and you want to round them / truncate them to integers?

Comment: @JacobRitchie Yes,ther are floats,need to be converted to integers.

Comment: Your way of converting to integers is probably incorrect here, then. The int() function just discards the decimal, it doesn't round correctly. You would need to use the round() function for that.

Comment: @JacobRitchie No because values are 1.200000e+03

Comment: OK, I guess it's fine in your case, then.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Staying as close to your proposed solution as possible, this should print out the line numbers for all lines containing your chosen `num`.

```
import itertools
with open('base.txt','r') as f:
    lst = map(int, itertools.imap(float, f))

num=1200

line_number = 1
for line in lst:
    if num == line:
        print (line_number)
    line_number += 1
```

**Edit**

However, your code just truncates the floats in your file - it will not round them correctly. `1200.9` becomes `1200` instead of `1201`, for instance.

If this isn't a problem in your case, that is fine. However, in general it would be better to change your

```
lst = map(int, itertools.imap(float, f))
```

function call to something like

```
lst = map(int,map(round, itertools.imap(float, f)))
```

Answer (score 2):

You can use `enumerate()`:

```
with open('base.txt', 'r') as f:
    for i, line in enumerate(f):
        if num == int(line):
            print i
```

Answer (score 1):

If you just want to print the line numbers, then you need to keep track of what line you are on.

Also, this code doesn't read the entire contents of the file into memory at once. (Useful for large files).

```
num = 1200

line_num = 0
with open('base.txt','r') as f:
    line_num += 1
    for line in f:
        if int(line) == num:
            print line_num
```